# need to change null and false to true in csv file through powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a csvfile. I need to replace the null("") and false in exported to true using powershell script. The text is like

```
"Name";"Type";"UserStories";"Option";"Date";"Exported"

"gddyd";"wt.org.Whdjh";"U6854";"";"";"false" 

"xxxxxx";"xt.org.yy";"U68678";"",""
```

After run the command the output should be

'''                                                               "Name";"Type";"UserStories";"Option";"Date";"Exported"

"gddyd";"wt.org.Whdjh";"U6854";"";"";"true"

"xxxxxx";"xt.org.yy";"U68678";"","true"

'''

Comment: please read
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#load file as simple textfile    
$content = get-content [path]

#replace    
$content = $content -replace '""|"false"','"true"'

#write file to disk
$content | set-content [path]
```

Comment: only  for exported object I need to change not for date option.. If I use the above code every null  and false in the text replaced by true